# finding duplicates in a column without dropping

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Input:

```
In [4]: df1
Out[4]: 
   A  B
0  1  1
1  2  2
2  1  3
3  2  4
4  3  5
5  4  6
6  3  7
7  3  8
```

Here I have to get only the duplicated items in the "A" column of df1. I used df1['A'].duplicated() function it gives me output by dropping one column. But my expected output is as below.

Expected Output:

```
In [7]: df2
Out[7]: 
   A  B
0  1  1
1  1  3
2  2  2
3  2  4
4  3  5
5  3  7
6  3  8
```

Comment: I would suggest to read Pandas documentaion of every function you do not know and want to use. Could be helpful `https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html`

Comment: I have to drop the fifth index which is unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df[df['A'].duplicated(keep=False)]
```

the `keep=False` option indicates to flag all duplicates